# How to parse JSON extract array

Tags: json, go

I work with Go.

I would like to parse a JSON file. But I only need just one array from the JSON file, not all the structure.

This is the JSON file : [link](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Python)

I only need the array of `items`.

How can I extract just this array from the JSON?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: It seems to be an easy task, but I not sure exactly what you want. maybe an example to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends of the definition of your structs. if you want only the array of items, you should unmarshal the main structure and then get the items array.

something like this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Structure struct {
    Items []Item `json:"items"`
}
type Item struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("myjson.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    structure := new(Structure)
    json.Unmarshal(data, structure)
    theArray := structure.Items
    fmt.Println(theArray)
}
```

The Unmarshal will ignore the fields you don't have defined in your struct. so that means you should add only what you whant to unmarshal

I used this JSON

```
{
    "total_count": 123123,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```