# How to print json value in golang

Tags: json, go

I have some json and want to print value but I don't know how to print from json format like this

```
"order_items":[  
      {  
         "total":1,
         "unitprice":1,
         "price":1,
         "create_date":"2019-06-07 13:51:36",
         "flow_no":"1234",
         "code":"4567",
         "quantiry":1,
         "discount_ctotal":0,
         "img":"",
         "fname":"first_name",
         "specs":"256"
      }
   ],
```

How can I print `code` value from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang parse JSON extract array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064983/golang-parse-json-extract-array)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a `struct` that has the data you're looking for. If all you care about is the `code`, then that's all you need to define.

```golang
type OrderItem struct {
    Code string `json:"code"`
}
```

Then just unmarshal your JSON into a slice of `OrderItem`s.

```golang
var orderItems []OrderItem
if err := json.Unmarshal(yourJson, &orderItems); err != nil {
    // handle errors in deserialization
}
```

Then do whatever you want with the output.

```golang
for _, orderItem := range orderItems {
    code := orderItem.Code
    // do something with it? I don't know
    fmt.Println(code)  // I guess?
}
```